# difficulty in understanding the synchronized definition

Tags: multithreading, scala, synchronized

I am learning to write code in multi-threading. I understand the literal meaning of synchronized operator in Scala. But, when I run the following code, I do not understand the output.

```
package examples
import scala.concurrent.ops._

object concurrent extends App {

    class BoundedBuffer[A](N:Int) {
        var in = 0;
        var out = 0;
        var n = 0;

        def put(x:A) = synchronized {
          while(n>=N)
            wait()
          in = (in + 1)/N;
          n = n+1;
          println("In put.")
          if(n==1)
            notifyAll()
        }

        def get = synchronized {
          while(n==0)
            wait()
          out = (out + 1)%N;
          n = n-1;
          println("In get.")
          if(n == N-1)
            notifyAll()
        }
    }

    val buf = new BoundedBuffer[Int](10)
    spawn {
        while(true)
            buf.put(0);
    }
    spawn {
        while(true)
            buf.get;
    }
}
```

with synchronized in put and get, the function would continue forever, which is expected. But, when I remove the synchronized from the definition, the output will be

```
In put.
In put.
In get.
In get.
```

Could Anyone explain why the results look like this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sort of puzzling behavior is why we now have much better (more cognitively tractable and less error-prone) tools for writing concurrent and distributed systems. I'm talking about Akka. If you're writing concurrent systems, it would behoove you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM's memory model has no guarantees for [sequential consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency) if you don't use something like `volatile` or `synchronized`. This means that each thread essentially has an independent view of the current value of `n`.

My guess is that something like this is happening:

1. The first thread spawns
2. First thread runs `put` twice and gets stuck waiting (I guess `N=2`?)
3. The second thread spawns, getting the current view of `n=2`
4. Second thread runs `get` twice, bringing `n` down to 0, and gets stuck waiting
5. Since there's no synchronization construct here each thread maintains its private view of the value of `n`, and it never changes—they just stay stuck in the `while` loops

Try making `n` [volatile](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.volatile) and see what happens. (I don't that will give you 100% correct behavior, but I don't think it will get stuck either.)